# CSS word-wrap property not working for label tag in Bootstrap

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I have a quiz game setup on bootstrap. Here is the code:

```
<div class="col-md-12">
   <div class="row">
      <div class="col-md-12" style="padding-bottom:20px; text-align:center;">
         <h1>4 . In the three stage theory of memory, the first stage is called short-term memory.</h1>
      </div>
   </div>
   <div class="row">
      <div class="col-md-6">
         <label class="btn btn-primary" style="font-size:25px; width:100%;" id="label_4_A">
         <input type="radio" name="224" value="A" id="option_4_A"> TRUE                                 </label>
      </div>
      <div class="col-md-6">
         <label class="btn btn-primary" style="font-size:25px; width:100%;" id="label_4_B">
         <input type="radio" name="224" value="B" id="option_4_B"> FALSE                                    </label>
      </div>
   </div>
   <div class="row">
      <div class="col-md-6">
         <label class="btn btn-primary" style="font-size:25px; width:100%;" id="label_4_C">
         <input type="radio" name="224" value="C" id="option_4_C"> Partially True                                   </label>
      </div>
      <div class="col-md-6">
         <label class="btn btn-primary" style="font-size:25px; width:100%;" id="label_4_D">
         <input type="radio" name="224" value="D" id="option_4_D"> Partially False                                  </label>
      </div>
   </div>
   <hr>
   <input type="button" name="next2" value="Next" id="nt" onclick="hideandshow('4','5') " class="btn btn-success">  
   <input type="hidden" value="3" name="game_id">
</div>
```

The problem is with the label. When the label text is longer than the width of the column, the text disappears. I want it to break automatically and continue in new line. I tried using

```
<label class="btn btn-primary" style="font-size:25px; width:100%; word-wrap: break-word;" id="label_4_B">
```

But it doesn't seem to work with labels I believe. Would be greatful if I can get help from this community.
Thank You.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to override the `white-space` property, which Bootstrap sets to `nowrap` on `.btn`:

```css
label.btn {
  white-space: initial;
}

.col-md-12 { width: 200px }
```

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<div class="col-md-12">
   <div class="row">
      <div class="col-md-12" style="padding-bottom:20px; text-align:center;">
         <h1>4 . In the three stage theory of memory, the first stage is called short-term memory.</h1>
      </div>
   </div>
   <div class="row">
      <div class="col-md-6">
         <label class="btn btn-primary" style="font-size:25px; width:100%;" id="label_4_A">
         <input type="radio" name="224" value="A" id="option_4_A"> TRUE                                 </label>
      </div>
      <div class="col-md-6">
         <label class="btn btn-primary" style="font-size:25px; width:100%;" id="label_4_B">
         <input type="radio" name="224" value="B" id="option_4_B"> FALSE                                    </label>
      </div>
   </div>
   <div class="row">
      <div class="col-md-6">
         <label class="btn btn-primary" style="font-size:25px; width:100%;" id="label_4_C">
         <input type="radio" name="224" value="C" id="option_4_C"> Partially True                                   </label>
      </div>
      <div class="col-md-6">
         <label class="btn btn-primary" style="font-size:25px; width:100%;" id="label_4_D">
         <input type="radio" name="224" value="D" id="option_4_D"> Partially False                                  </label>
      </div>
   </div>
   <hr>
   <input type="button" name="next2" value="Next" id="nt" onclick="hideandshow('4','5') " class="btn btn-success">  
   <input type="hidden" value="3" name="game_id">
</div>
```